# as2 simple for loop not populating textbox

Tags: loops, actionscript-2, for-loop

I have got an xml file that brings text into a flash movie in the form of an array,
I need to population some textboxes and want to do this using a for loop.
My loop look like this:

```
        for(var i=0; i<first_array.length; i++){


            this.animation1.text_mc[i].txt[i].htmlText = first_array[i];


        }
```

if i hardcode the path, without [i], it works, am i missing something really obvious?

Answer (score 0):

sorted it, so i'll answer my own question:

```
this.animation1["text_mc" + i]["txt" + i].htmlText = first_array[i];
```

hopefully this will help someone else.

Marvin